# How to enable the url in icefaces project

Tags: java, jsf, url-rewriting, icefaces

My Icefaces project is running well in the tomcat server on following url

```
http://localhost:8085/projectName/
```

I can select which page to load default in index page. But what I wand is to access it by

```
http://localhost:8085/projectName/pageOne
```

I do not know how to do this, and I tried googling but found nothing relevant. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have a lot of pages like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking that you need the URL pattern mapped to page, not the page name exactly then for JSF go for [`PrettyFaces`](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/)

Comment: thanx for the reply, but I dont want to replace the url, I have many pages, so simply i want to access them by url. like ....projectName/page1 or ...projectName/page2

Comment: so your pages needs to be in public spaces directly and give it extension to access the page